# How to get lastModified attribute of clipboard api in javascript?

Tags: clipboarddata

I'm accessing clipboard data on copy/paste event in browser. It's working fine. I want to check when system clipboard was lastModified. It's a readonly attribute available in clipboard interface. I am new to JS. Can anybody help?
Here is the link to clipboard api:
https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#dom-clipboarditem-lastmodified

[image]